# How are keys shared safely for block / stream encryption?

Tags: block-cipher, keys, key-exchange, stream-cipher

I've picked up a grad level computer security class. I read a brief overview on block and stream encryption. I understand and have used PGP in the past and it make since to share your public key. Since the keys for block and stream encryption are extremely import for others not to find them. How do you share them in a private way? Are there other methods to keep them safe if you send it over via email / other form of comms?

Comment: Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange, RSA-KEM etc. You will learn that later in your course. Did you check the textbook on public-key encryption?

Comment: @kelalaka Please correct me if I'm wrong. If we use public-key encryption doesn't that make it asymmetric? Is that the best way to share a key from symmetric? I did read over the section on  public-key encryption but, I think i might of been in the mindset of this only applying to PGP / RSA.

Comment: Yes, we mostly encrypt with symmetric encryption. We prefer hybrid encryption since the public key encryptions are much slower than symmetric encryptions. In hybrid encryption the key is sent/exchanged with public key system and the exchanged key used for symmetric encryption.